# devise rails - customizing error handling and views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Using rails 3 , devise 1.2 
What should a customized sign up view look like? The default is this:

```
%h2 Sign Up
= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
```

`= devise_error_messages!`

can i replace resource with something like User model?
And how are errors handled? I read that devise.error_messages should not be used as its just a stub. Very new to rails and devise, so all suggestions/simple solutions welcome.

Answer (score 3):

The devise_error_message is just an helper to check all #errors in your resource. So you just need define you own view of managing your errors. By exemple the simplest is :

```
- unless @user.errors.empty?
  %ul
    - @user.errors.each do |error|
      %li= error.full_message
```